# Android matcher Regex

Tags: android, regex

Something that seems very simple and is working everywhere else but not in Android. I want matcher to return TRUE if a string is anything but A+. Is negative lookbehind not valid in Android 6.0? Here is my Regex that is not working:

^((?!A\+).*)$

If I pass A, A- or A+ it is returning FALSE. It should only return FALSE for A+.

Comment: s != 'A+'   Not really a good use of regex for single case true.  Also Show us the code it's so much easier to cut n paste code to try it out.

Comment: Why won't you use `!String#startsWith("A+")` method? It'll do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plus sign is not escaped: Try the following:

`^((?!A\\+).*)$`

Comment: I had a single slash in there but not the double.

Comment: Yes - the single slash is reserved for Java-escaping. So you need a double for a regex escape.